# Differentiable and continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

1) **Let be $g$ be a continuous function at $x=0$. Prove that $f(x) = x g(x) $ is differentiable at $x = 0$**

Here is my attempt:

I have to show that $f(x)$ is differentiable at x = 0.
\begin{align*}
f'(0) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {f(x) - f(0)\over x}\\
      &= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} {xg(x) - xg(0)\over x}\\
      &= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x{g(x) - g(0)\over x} = x g'(0)
\end{align*}

Now, we have $f'(0) = x g'(0)$. Can I conclude that $f(x)$ is differentiable?

**2) Suppose that $f(x) =0$ and $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$. Prove that there is a function $g$ that is continuous at $x=0$ and satisfies $f(x)=xg(x)$.**

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {f(x) - f(0)\over x}&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {f(x)\over x}\\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} {xg(x)\over x}\\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x). 
\end{align*}

Then I show $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) = g(0) $. Is my prove sufficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), the second last equal sign is wrong. There is a common factor $x$ on the numerator and it is eliminated by the $x$ on the denominator. The result should be

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x) - g(0) = g(0) - g(0) = 0 $$

For (2), existence is asked and if you go for a constructive proof, you should write down your construction of $g$ first. It is not clear that what your $g$ is. Indeed, intuitively you would just let $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$, but this is undefined at $x = 0$. Therefore an obvious modification is

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} f'(0) \quad \text{when } x = 0 \\ \frac{f(x)}{x} \quad \text {otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then for $x \neq 0, f(x) = xg(x)$ by definition and $f(0) = 0 = 0 \times g(0)$. Hence $f(x) = xg(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Also, the continuity of $g$ at $x = 0$ is explained by the differentiability of $f$ at $x = 0$. In fact, you can show further the function $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ since $f$ and the identity map is continuous at $x \neq 0$ and so is the quotient where the denominator is not $0$.

Comment: Yeah, I found that. Is there any other error? What about 2? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

Answer (score 2):

(1) You cannot refer to $g'(0)$ because it is not known that $g$ is differentiable - you are only told that $g$ is continuous.

**Hint**.

- Write down exactly what is meant by the statement "$g$ is continuous at $0$".
- You have got as far as
  $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xg(x)-xg(0)}{x}$$
  correctly.  Make an obvious simplification and then apply the previous point.

**Edit**.  As pointed out by Andres Caicedo, this is not in fact correct, it should be
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{xg(x)}{x}\ .$$
But it is still easy to finish the problem from here.

(2) Obviously you want $g(x)=f(x)/x$; but obviously this does not work if $x=0$.  Since $g$ is supposed to be continuous at $0$, you need
$$g(0)=\lim_{x\to0}g(x)\ .$$
So, work out this limit, then define
$$g(x)=\cases{f(x)/x&if $x\ne0$\cr \cdots&if $x=0$.\cr}$$
See if you can fill in this gap and complete the problem.  Good luck!

Comment: For 1). I will get $f'(0)=0$ then I am done.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user179313 Hopefully not, since that is incorrect in general.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Why so?  Looks correct to me.

Comment: $f(0)$ is not $xg(0)$. In fact, that makes no sense, since $f(0)$ is a number, and $xg(0)$ is a function.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Thanks, I should have looked more closely at the OP's working.  Answer updated.

Comment: So I have $f'(0)= \lim_{x\rightarrow o} g(x) = g(0) $. Then f is differentiable at x = 0 ? Thanks guys!